# Retrieving password whereby "SH1"

Tags: sha1

My table contains a column "pass" for encrypted passwords inserted as "SHA1('$password')".
I want to retrieve that column to see both:encrypted password and "original" password so I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `fname`, `email`, `pass` FROM `list`"; 
$result = $dbcon->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
echo "{$row[2]}. 'encoded:'. {SHA1($row[2])}<br>";
}
$dbcon->close();
?>
```

I only get encoded passwords.
I there a way I can see "real passwords" in my table?
Thanks

Comment: No. You should never store — or have a way for the application to retrieve — an unencrypted password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot see the real passwords.  That's the purpose for using a hash function.  But hashing alone is not enough.  These two sources will give in depth explanation of what you should be doing any WHY:

- [CrackStation.Net](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

  [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846/)

Answer (score 1):

[`SHA-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is a one-way hash, meaning that you can't get back the original value after performing the hashing. In a situation like yours, where you are storing passwords, that's a very-very good thing, since you shouldn't be able to read plain-text passwords.